# Does it matters if JS or CSS codes are compressed twice by YUI compressor?

Tags: javascript, css, compression, yui

As mentioned in the topic, does it matters? For example, I have 2 files: j1.min.js and j2.js. j1.min.js is already compressed by the YUI compressor. Can I concatenate these two files first and got an file called combined.js and then use YUI compressor to compress it? In this case, the ji.min.js is compressed twice.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but it also shouldn't happen in your build process. It also shouldn't make much of a worthwhile difference.

Comment: Why it shouldn't happen in my build?

Answer (score 0):

That should not matter. That is, it should neither break your build, nor should it make a noticeable difference in the size of the resulting compressed file.